# No me quiere enviar el formulario y me genera Error ReferenceError: range is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[1]:No me quiere servir el codigo, me genera error de no definido range

Comment: Buenas, Oscar, bienvenido al sitio, ¿le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? Aparte, ¿has visto cómo ha quedado tu pregunta? Por favor, añade tu código como texto formateado para que podamos ayudarte. ¿Cómo has definido el formulario? ¿Qué estás haciendo para enviarlo? ¿A qué rango hace referencia ese error? Tal y como está la pregunta no se puede hacer mucho.